# Print values in REST API

Tags: php, rest

The HTTP Rest API shows me the values above :

```
        id  514
        filial  5
        name    "COD. 514 20 Mb RES. TRL"
        nome_amigavel   "20 Mb"
        mensalidade "89.90"
        desconto    "0.00"
        ativo   1
        tipo    1
        instalacao  "300.00"
        bnd_up  2000
        bnd_down    20000
        1   
        id  422
        filial  4
        name    "COD. 069 30 Mb TRANSPORTE"
        nome_amigavel   "30 Mb"
        mensalidade "1500.00"
        desconto    "0.00"
        ativo   1
        tipo    3
        instalacao  "1500.00"
        bnd_up  0
        bnd_down    30000
        2
```

How Can I "print" or "Echo" a specific value or a single value in a PHP file ????

```
                                  <?php



          $curl = curl_init();
          curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://services.west.net.br/rest/server.php/planos",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                          "authorization: Basic YXaBepOmsadsahpaacGVwwaybassdwsadsadsawd3BpYSBw0cmddF2YWdaalbSBiaXBdlbmFkbw==",
                          "cache-control: no-cache",
                          "content-type: application/json",
                      ),
                  ));
          $response = curl_exec($curl);
          $err = curl_error($curl);

          curl_close($curl);

          if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
          } else {
            echo $response;
          }
          ?>
```

Im try this , but no sucess , im newbiee in rest api , and try some examples from the web, please help with some!!!

Comment: i try something like above:  bot not sucess:

Comment: you tried like what? show us your code

Comment: i edit my code , look there

Answer (score 0):

with the code below

```
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl); //<!---- $curl_responce instead of $output
if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . 
    var_export($info)); //<!--- this is pointless IMO
}
curl_close($curl);
$decoded = json_decode($curl_response);  ///<!--- set to results to $decoded, also no second value ie. "json_decode($curl_response, 1);"

if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
}
echo 'response ok!';
var_export($decoded->response);

//==================================//
// looks like someone just dropped the code below
// this line in. ha ha.

$result = json_decode($output, 1);  //<!--- output does not exist, but this is already done above. so use $decoded instead of $output.
 // check if an id came back
 if (!empty($result['id'])) {
  $deal_id = $result['id'];
  return $deal_id;
 } else {
  return false;
 }

echo $deal_id;
```

the variable `$output` is never set, instead use `$decoded`. This is because `$result` also does not exist and is instead `$curl_response` in your code above.  Sense you already have it decoded, there is no need to decode it again.

That said, in the `json_decode` there, the second parameter is not set to `true`, when that is the case you get an object back and not an array as you might expect.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
>
> **assoc**
>   When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.
>
> The second option is JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY that has the same effect as setting assoc to TRUE.

To fix the part your having trouble with you should be able to replace the stuff below the `=====` with this.

```
 // check if an id came back
 if (!empty($output->id)) {
    $deal_id = $output->id;
    return $deal_id;
 } else {
    return false;  // should echo something instead of returning.
 }

echo $deal_id;
```

Also to remove the other output, comment these 2 lines.

```
 echo 'response ok!';
 var_export($decoded->response);
```

Comment: OK,  i edit my code , look there.. its right now ... but it prints me ALL the Values ...  how can i print just one value from the array !!! ??????